# How to write a table with "checked" and "unchecked" cell easily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to a table to accomplish assign auth to users, so that I can check a cell to provide an auth to something to a user.

the table should be like:

[image: auth table]

when an user check the box, the color changes to indicator that he/she will have authorized to access that subject.

The data now I use is like(The structure can be changed since I can control this):

```
["subject/user","user1","user2","user3","user4","user5"],
["subject1","X","X","√","√","√"],
["subject2","√","√","√","√","√"],
["subject3","√","√","√","√","√"],
["subject4","√","√","√","√","√"],
["subject5","√","√","√","√","√"]
```

where the first array is the first row(title), and the rest represents they have the auth or not on a certain subject.

I now accomplish this by `dataTables` with

```
var titles = data.shift();
var columns = [];
for(var i=0; i<titles.length; i++){
columns.push({
    "sTitle":titles[i],
     "class":"center"
});
}

....//
$("#authManageUserListTable").dataTable({
            "aaData":data,
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]], // disable default sort
            "aoColumns":columns,
....//
"fnDrawCallback":function(oSettings){
    $("#authManageUserListTable tbody td").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "√"){
            $(this).text("");
            $(this).attr("isChecked",true);
            $(this).css("background-color","#2674A7");
        }else if($(this).text() == "X"){
            $(this).text("");
            $(this).attr("isChecked",false);
            $(this).css("background-color","#aaaaaa");
        }
    });
}


....//

//and then 

 $('#authManageUserListTable tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    if(isTrue($(this).attr("isChecked"))){
        $(this).css("background-color","#aaaaaa");
        $(this).attr("isChecked",false);
    }
    else if(isFalse($(this).attr("isChecked"))){
        $(this).css("background-color","#2674A7");
        $(this).attr("isChecked",true);
    }
    console.log(this);
} );
```

But my concerns are :

1. How can I get the new re-set data to represent the new auth after user manipulation. Something should be changed when I check/uncheck the cell?
2. I need to add two button(span) to the the row besides all the user, representing "check all", "uncheck all" to indicate assign all auth to this user on all subjects. How can I do that?

I am using `jquery.dataTables 1.9.4` but if there are any libs that are easy to achieve this, it will be also highly appreciated.

Comment: @ Jaskey I have faced such problem what I did I make the copy of `original array` and on check box change I update the copied array value. To do so I have to add an extra column named index and hide it to encounter the problem like if user sort the rows and then check/uncheck

Answer (score 2):

1. Your first question.

When you want to change something in Datatable, you must change the dataTable object. If you change only the HTML your changes will disappear when the state of dataTable changes(filter, order, etc).
So if you have to make changes in dataTable, you have to access to fnSettings and change there all that you want.

Example:

```
$('#authManageUserListTable tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
var table = $("#authManageUserListTable").dataTable();
// Get the position of the current data from the node
var aPos = table.fnGetPosition( this );
var aPosCell = aPos[1];
var aPosRow = aPos[0]
var tdcell = table.fnSettings().aoData[aPosRow].nTr;
if($(this).attr("isChecked")=='true'){
//$(this).css("background-color","#aaaaaa");
//$(this).attr("isChecked",false);
   $('td',tdcell)[aPosCell].setAttribute('isChecked','false');
   $('td',tdcell).eq(aPosCell).css("background-color","#aaaaaa");
}
else if($(this).attr("isChecked")=='false'){
//$(this).css("background-color","#2674A7");
//$(this).attr("isChecked",true);
   $('td',tdcell).eq(aPosCell).attr('isChecked','true');
   $('td',tdcell).eq(aPosCell).css("background-color","#2674A7");
}
});
```

2.Second question.
You can add one row at the end And then, when clicked on any of this td, get the cell, and modify the two attributes(isChecked, colorbackground) of all tr of this cell.

```
// The last tr is for all grants
$('#authManageUserListTable tbody tr').eq(-1).on( 'click', 'td', function (){ 
 var table = $("#authManageUserListTable").dataTable();
 // Get the position of the current data from the node
 var aPosCell = table.fnGetPosition( this );
 $(table.fnSettings().aoData).each(function(){
 $(this).nTr.cells.eq(aPosCell).attr('isChecked','true');
 $(this).nTr.cells.eq(aPosCell).css("background-color","#2674A7");
})
//The second to last is for any grants
$('#authManageUserListTable tbody tr').eq(-1).on( 'click', 'td', function (){ 
 var table = $("#authManageUserListTable").dataTable();
 // Get the position of the current data from the node
 var aPosCell = table.fnGetPosition( this );
 $(table.fnSettings().aoData).each(function(){
 $(this).nTr.cells.eq(aPosCell).attr('isChecked','false');
 $(this).nTr.cells.eq(aPosCell).css("background-color","#aaaaaa");
})
} );
```

Remember to apply this changes in DrawCallBack too.
I think not have any error, but if find any error, tell me.
I hope this can be helpful for you.
Tell me if you have any problem.

Comment: Could I have a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Here see the 1st question, when I have the second, I will show you. https://jsfiddle.net/nd2sjkq1/5/